# How can show again dialog of volume change android app

Tags: android

I have a player app with a seekbar for volume control inside. I use this code:

```java
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
    { 
        int index = volumeSeekbar.getProgress(); 
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(index + 1); 
        return true; 
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        int index = volumeSeekbar.getProgress(); 
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(index - 1); 
        return true; 
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

The code works well. Now when I press hardware volume control down/up button my seekbar moves. But now I have an issue with the volume dialog in Android. When i press the hardware button it doesn't show anymore. I mean the dialog in the picture:

[image]

What can I do to fix it and show the volume dialog as usual?

**Edit:**

Here is my code for using `AudioManager`:

```java
 private void initControls() {
     try {
         volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
         audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
         volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
         volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                               .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   

         volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}

             @Override
             public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}

             @Override
             public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                 audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
             }
         });
     }
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog is not shown because you are consuming the key event in the `onKeyDown()` function. Therefore the event is not propagated further and the volume dialog is not shown.

There is a simple solution for this. In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) for the `onKeyDown()` function it says that you have to return `false` to prevent the event from being consumed. Now the dialog will show again.

Nevertheless, I don't think you are using the right approach to receive the information about volume. When the volume dialog shows up, the user can drag the seekbar in it and change the volume, such change is not reflected in calls to `onKeyDown()` function. You could utilize [`AudioManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) and its `getStreamVolume()` function:

```java
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: i added my code for audio manager can u take a look ? im using AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, already but dont know if that is the right way

Comment: Well, the code is quite ok, just one thing. If the user changes volume in the volume dialog, the seekbar is not updated. For that there is one rather clumsy solution - repeatedly call `getStreamVolume()` in a background thread. Not ideal but works.

Comment: thanks i see, i think that can be a solution thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a flag (`AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI`).  [Here's a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733061/1226799) that helped me.